# Connection issues on one IP but not another on the same host/nic

Tags: networking, nginx, linux-networking

I'm debugging an issue where some http requests randomly take longer times than normally. (Normal being a few ms, abnormally being 1000ms up to a minute or more)

The host has several IP's and the service I'm working with is proxied by nginx on two of those IPs.

If I send requests to the first IP, everything works as expected and all requests are fast.
If I send requests to the second IP, some requests randomly take several seconds or more.

Both IPs are on the same nic:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq      master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0c:29:5e:47:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
link/ether 00:0c:29:5e:47:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.10.73/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global bond0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.10.72/32 scope global bond0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.10.75/32 scope global bond0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.10.76/32 scope global bond0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.10.54/32 scope global bond0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So, for example:

```
curl -H "Host: xxx" http://192.168.10.54:6700/test
```

will randomly be slow, while

```
curl -H "Host: xxx" http://192.168.10.75:6700/test
```

is always fast.

Both IPs are served by the same nginx server block:

```
server {
        listen 192.168.10.75:6700;
        listen 192.168.10.54:6700;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://...;
        }
}
```

I've checked open ports, but there are just a few hundred connections on each IP.

This is on Linux (3.16.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.64-2 (2019-04-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux)
The server is running in vmWare, so NIC is reported as `0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller (rev 01)`

I have no iptable rules

I'm not sure how to proceed with debugging and would appreciate any hints :-)

Concrete questions:

- What settings can be different on IP level on the same bond that I could check
- What metrics can I check to give me hints on the cause
- Could something else on the network cause such effects (duplicate IPs, vlan configuration, ..?)
- What could be "overloaded" or saturated on IP but not another?

Comment: What network cards/chipset(s) are in use? Have you discounted a bad network cable or switch port?

Comment: for me ots unclear because you curl port 80 and on the server bloxk using 6700? whats the rest? what does nginx -T say?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the port when o wrote the example. Of course I query port 6700..

Comment: Added info about the NIC, it's running on vmWare. I can check real hardware tomorrow. Cables are not replaced yet - but Ive written it off as both IPs run on same NIC and cables..

Comment: Why do you have multiple IPs and bonded ethernet running off a single interface? On a virtual machine?

Comment: add output of eth-tool for both nic and bond.